# Conditions for a smooth optimizer?

Tags: functions, derivatives, optimization

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to determine conditions (on $f$ and/or $X$) under which the maximizer defined by
\begin{align}
\hat x(\alpha) = \operatorname{argmax}\limits_{x\in X}\,f(x,\alpha)
\end{align}
is a smooth function in $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^m$ (by function I mean that there is a unique $\hat x(\alpha)$ for each $\alpha$). Any tips or guidance?

Comment: Are you seeing $\hat{x}$ as a true function, in the sense that to each $\alpha$ there corresponds one and only one $\hat{x}(\alpha)$?

Comment: @Siminore Yes, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have trouble in cases where $f(\cdot, \alpha)$ can have non-unique maxima for some $\alpha$.  Typically as $\alpha$ passes through such a point, the argmax will jump discontinuously.  To avoid such problems, you may want to assume $f$ is strictly concave in $x$ (though there are some more general conditions). If $f$ is smooth and the Hessian matrix with respect to $x$ is negative definite (and thus invertible), I think you can use the Implicit Function Theorem.